# Load WordPress images of posts and show them on another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having some trouble with WordPress to show images that belong to a certain post on another page.
What I'm looking for is a homepage that lists all posts within a certain category and show the title, the excerpt and a *'view examples'* link. The view examples link would show all images that belong to the post in a LightBox, but on the homepage.

So far I have this, but now I'm sort of stuck.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=15&order=DSC'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="pakket-block">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <span class="read_more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="shadowbox">View examples</a></span>    
            </div> <!-- /.pakket-block -->
        </div> <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty rough example (Couldn't test this in my current environment)

This should send you in the right direction to fetching all images attached to a page.

Put this function in functions.php:

```
    function get_match( $regex, $content ) {
        preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }
```

And this in the template file:

```
    query_posts('cat=15&order=DSC');
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();


        // Extract the shortcode arguments from the $page or $post
        $shortcode_args = shortcode_parse_atts(get_match('/\[gallery\s(.*)\]/isU', $post->post_content));

        $ids = $shortcode_args["ids"];

        // get the attachments specified in the "ids" shortcode argument
        $attachments = get_posts(
            array(
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'post_status' => 'inherit', 
                'post_type' => 'attachment', 
                'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
                'order' => 'menu_order ID', 
                'orderby' => 'post__in',
            )
        );


        print_r($attachments);


    endwhile; endif; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not** use `query_posts` for additional post queries. See: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

What you need can be done with 2 [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Examples), one to grab the posts in the category. And a second one, inside the first, to grab the attachments using `post_parent` (like in Richard Denton's answer) with the ID of the first loop.

You can create your own functions inside `functions.php` to do the job. So, in your template file you'd simply have (generic code outline):

```
<?php print_category_15(); ?>
```

And the functions:

```
function print_category_15() {
    $posts = get_posts( $your_arguments );
    if( $posts ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            // Print titles and excerpts
            print_childrens_of_15( $post->ID );
        }
    }
}

function print_childrens_of_15( $parent ) {
    $children = get_posts( $your_arguments_for_attachments );
    if( $children ) {
        foreach ( $children as $child ) {
            // Print your hidden divs to be used in the ShadowBox
        }
    }
}
```